# PHPExcel как сгруппировать данные при чтении

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Если на активном листе видно, что данные сгруппированы и выделены синим, как их перенести в MySQL   с дополнительным полем по названию выделенного синим к группе записей,  идущих после каждого синего поля?
[image]

Comment: Покажите код, которым вы разбираете excel.
Разве phpexcel не устарел сто лет назад?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
//Функция принимает имя xls файла, считывает его, занося данные ячеек строк в массив, и возвращает этот массыв как результат
function getXLS($xls){
    include_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($xls);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    $aSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $array = array();//этот массив будет содержать массивы содержащие в себе значения ячеек каждой строки
    //получим итератор строки и пройдемся по нему циклом
    foreach($aSheet->getRowIterator() as $row){

        //получим итератор ячеек текущей строки
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        //пройдемся циклом по ячейкам строки
        $item = array();//этот массив будет содержать значения каждой отдельной строки
        foreach($cellIterator as $cell){
            //заносим значения ячеек одной строки в отдельный массив
            //array_push($item, iconv('utf-8', 'cp1251', $cell->getCalculatedValue()));
            array_push($item, $cell->getCalculatedValue());



        }
        //заносим массив со значениями ячеек отдельной строки в "общий массв строк"
        array_push($array, $item);
    }
    return $array;
}

$xlsData = getXLS('xls/price-syktyvkar.xls'); //извлеаем данные из XLS
```

$ass=array();
foreach($xlsData as $cell) {

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {

    if ($cell[0]=='Код') echo $cell[$i]."-".$i." ";
    //echo "<br>";
    }

echo "<br>";
```

}

Comment: здесь я пытаюсь вывести хотя бы группы - те что синим цветом выделены, под каждой из которых все записи относятся